# How do I fix the Werror=parentheses (suggest parentheses around assignment) error?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a line of code which does both assignment and condition. I could split it into two lines but I'm just curious about the error message thrown.

```
  if ( parameters->__size = m_Elements.size() )
```

Got this error: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Werror=parentheses]

I tried:

```
   if ( (parameters->__size) = (m_Elements.size()) )
```

The error doesn't go away. But I feel I have done what I was prompted to do and added parentheses around the assignment. Why doesn't the error go away? What am I missing?

Comment: `if((parameters->__size = m_Elements.size()))`

Comment: Note that `__size` identifier is reserved to the language implementation, so if you define a member by that name, then behaviour of the program will be undefined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To convince the compiler that the assignment is *really* what you want, you need to enclose the *whole expression* in parentheses, like this:

```cpp
    if ( ( parameters->__size = m_Elements.size() ) ) 
    //...
```

Without this, the compiler thinks that you *may* have made a mistake, using assignment (`=`) instead of the comparison (`==`) operator.

Comment: Sometimes, coding `if ( ( parameters->__size = m_Elements.size() ) != 0 )` might make the code more readable

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I agree 100%. But, if the programmer is looking for terse code that avoids warnings, then the extra enclosing `(...)` is the MNC (minimal necessary change).

Answer (score 4):

The warning suggests you to put parentheses around the assignment expression, not around the individual operands. You can silence it via

```
if ( ( parameters->__size = m_Elements.size() ) )
  // ^                                        ^
```

However, ask yourself if this is really any better than the original. I suppose you turned on the warning for a reason and the suggested fix does indeed silence the warning, but the code can still cause the same confusion as before for a reader. You can do this instead:

```
parameters->__size = m_Elements.size();
if (parameters->__size)
```

Answer (score 1):

The message means that you should enclose in parentheses the assignment expression.

That is instead of

```
 if ( (parameters->__size) = (m_Elements.size()) )
```

you should write

```
 if ( ( parameters->__size = m_Elements.size() ) )
```

Such an approach allows to distinguish a typo when instead of the comparison operator `==` there is typed the assignment operator `=` and an intentional use of the assignment in a condition.

Comment: "should have..." as in "some compiler writer thinks it's good style to...". <g> The original code is valid and its meaning is well-defined.